# C# INSERT to SQL method exception when DateTime parameter is null

Tags: c#, sql

One of my parameter looks like this:

```cs
cmd.Parameters.Add("@last_sign_in_at", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = user.last_sign_in_at;
```

I know that User has null value in `last_sign_in_at`. Database accept nulls for this column but I get an exception:

> SqlException: The parameterized query '(@id int,@name nvarchar(18),@username nvarchar(11),@state nvarch' expects the parameter '@last_sign_in_at', which was not supplied.

Comment: Tip: if you use Dapper, it get things like this right *for you*, and avoids a lot of code: `connection.Execute(@"...SQL...", new { user.last_sign_in_at });`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using DBNull.Value:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@last_sign_in_at", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = (object)user.last_sign_in_at ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
```

Casting to object here is just for operator `??` to not complain about different types

Comment: Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'DateTime?' and 'DBNull'

Comment: expected that, you could use (object)user.last_sign_in_at?? (object)DBNull.Value

Comment: I used 
`cmd.Parameters.Add("@last_sign_in_at", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = user.last_sign_in_at ?? DateTime.Today;`

Comment: but that's not null, what do you mean? You inserted Today's time, you should use DBNull.Value, that's also obviously if your column is Nullable in SQL Table

Answer (score 1):

When using raw .net framework, I've always had to use the value `DBNull.Value`.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@last_sign_in_at", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: but  user.last_sign_in_at  is not always NULL but when it's null method trows an exception